# Dialog box does not accept input, stays on-top and hides everything under it. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop, desktop-icons, cups-lpd

Upon rebooting, I get dialog box

```
Authentication Required

Authentication is required to start 'cups.service'.
```

I can type in the password and click Authenticate, but then nothing happens. I can't see under the box. I can't move the box, can't cancel the dialog.

But, I can click on where I know the underneath icon to be and that click is accepted and the program in question runs.

Thank you in advance ...

I have recently done a clean install of 20.04.
[image]

Comment: I've got the exact same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 (also a clean install) the message is just "Authentication Required. To install or remove software, you need to authenticate." The dialog box is exactly the same otherwise: visible at the same location, hiding everything underneath but not blocking interaction with things underneath.

Comment: @Geil, yes. I think it doesn't matter what the application. Some dialogs just get stuck open on the new Ubuntu. Live patch just did an update and had me re-boot. Right now that stuck dialog does not appear, and I've been waiting for it for upwards of 3 hours. If it is still okay tomorrow, I'll post that as the solution. In the meantime, let live patch do its thing if it hasn't done so already. good luck.

Comment: @Geil
The upgrade seemed to work. But then, just yesterday, about a week later, that pesky dialog showed up again. Still having same issues.

Answer (score 2):

From the [comments](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1824874/comments/12) in the bug linked in the other answer, the following seems to get rid of the window , though I have absolutely no idea what actually is happening under the hood:

> "And when I press ALT+F2, then type "r" and press enter, it's gone!"

Comment: This doesn't work!

Comment: I found that reconnecting my 2nd monitor made it go away this time. So maybe trying to change video modes might do something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. When I reported the bug, this was the reply:

> *** This bug is a duplicate of bug 1824874 ***
>       https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1824874
>
> Thanks. That confirms this is a duplicate of bug 1824874.
>
> ** This bug has been marked a duplicate of bug 1824874    undismissable, unclickable authentication dialog left on screen
>   (top-left corner) after policykit authentication [pushModal:
>   invocation of begin_modal failed]